# How to deploy singleton legacy code in EJB to be instantiated multiple times?

Tags: jakarta-ee, singleton, ejb

We have a legacy validation framework that is singleton only and can not be used in a multi threaded way. We would like to instantiate multiple instances of singletons in stateless EJB's to speed up batch processing of files, however we are legally not allowed to change the source code of said framework.

Is there any workaround here to solve this problem? Thanks!

**EDIT:** Lots of subclasses in this framework are using singletons as well as static attributes, so no multi threading possible :-/

Comment: It seems to me that only using different classloaders for each framework instance seems to be a "quite complicated" option.

Comment: I was hoping someone could provide a solution that would not involve integrating the dreaded classloaders in our ejbs, but I guess that's the only potential solution to this problem  ;-) Thanks for your comment!

Answer (score 0):

Need more details about this legacy framework, but there is no relationship between singleton objects and multithreading performance. If this objects are stateless, you can process your files in paralel with no performance problems.

So, if you, for example, implement a Message Queue and Message Driven Beans, each process will be a MDB instance that will work at the same time. Work with threads API directly on server is not good.